# Batch listing question

Tags: batch-file

I'm writing a Batch script to compile a list of files as a string ("file1.txt file2.txt filr3.txt..."). I'm doing this since I want to run an application that requires to pass in a list of files to process.

All the files are in the same folder.

When I run the following code:

```
FOR /f "tokens=*" %%M IN ('dir * /b') DO (
    SET files=%files% %%M
)
ECHO END %files%
```

The echo at the end only gives the the last file processed and not the entire list. What's wrong with my implementation?

Thanks for any help you can give

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use delayed expansion:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=*" %%M in ('dir * /b') do (
  set files=!files! %%M
)
echo END %files%
```

You can see a documentation of that in `help set`:

> Delayed environment variable expansion is useful for getting around
>   the limitations of the current expansion which happens when a line
>   of text is read, not when it is executed.  The following example
>   demonstrates the problem with immediate variable expansion:
>
> ```
> set VAR=before
> if "%VAR%" == "before" (
>     set VAR=after
>     if "%VAR%" == "after" @echo If you see this, it worked
> )
> ```
>
> would never display the message, since the `%VAR%` in BOTH IF statements
>   is substituted when the first `IF` statement is read, since it logically
>   includes the body of the `IF`, which is a compound statement.  So the
>   `IF` inside the compound statement is really comparing "before" with
>   "after" which will never be equal.  Similarly, the following example
>   will not work as expected:
>
> ```
> set LIST=
> for %i in (*) do set LIST=%LIST% %i
> echo %LIST%
> ```
>
> in that it will *not* build up a list of files in the current directory,
>   but instead will just set the `LIST` variable to the last file found.
>   Again, this is because the `%LIST%` is expanded just once when the
>   `FOR` statement is read, and at that time the `LIST` variable is empty.
>   So the actual `FOR` loop we are executing is:
>
> ```
> for %i in (*) do set LIST= %i
> ```
>
> which just keeps setting `LIST` to the last file found.

Furthermore, you shouldn't ever use `for /f` to iterate over `dir` output as this can break in subtle ways. You need special treatment for file names with spaces and it breaks with raster fonts and Unicode. Basically you're saying “Hey, I'm running a command, tokenize its output converted into the current OEM codepage and try to work with that instead of just asking `for` to iterate over files”:

```
for %%M in (*) do ...
```

Comment: Thanks. This fixes everything.